# Error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django-forms

I'm getting an error and I'm getting crazy!

I created a form associated to a model. Everytime, when the form.is_valid() function is executed on my views.py, django shows the following error:

`Exception Type: AttributeError`

`Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Register(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django.form import ModelForm
from models.models import Register

class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Register
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models.models import Register
from register.forms import RegisterForm

def register(request):
    if 'user_email' in request.POST:
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST['user_email'])
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            retunr render_to_response('registered.html')

    return render_To_response('main.html')
```

PS_1: I show the value of the form in another page to check if it contains just the e-mail and it's ok, it just contains the e-mail.

PS_2: request.POST contains 'user_email' sure.

Please, could you help me to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
form = RegisterForm(request.POST['user_email'])
```

is incorrect. `Form`s should be passed the full mapping.

```
form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
```

The field name will then be different, but that is a separate issue (since you don't seem to be *outputting* the form in a page).

Comment: The problem is that If I delete ['user_email'], then, when django check `form.is_valid()`, it always returns false

Comment: I got the answer to my problem! The problem was that I was identifying the email id as "user_email" instead of "email". When the form is validated, the name of the form fields should be exactly the same that the fields come from the html template in the request.POST.

Thanks to all for your help!